# Menu subitem doesn't keep its position

Tags: menus, subdomains

I try to hide some menu items (from an unique menu) dynamically in functions.php. I have some subdomains. I add CSS classes to menu items and then I hide them according to the current subdomain. Here is my code :

```
add_filter( 'wp_get_nav_menu_items', 'hide_menu_item', 10, 3 );
function hide_menu_item ( $items, $menu, $args ) {
    $sub = array_shift((explode(".",$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])));

    if(!is_admin()){
        foreach ( $items as $key => $item ) {
            if ( $item->classes[0] == 'subdomain1' && $sub != 'part1' || $item->classes[0] == 'main' && $sub != 'domain') {
                unset( $items[$key] );
            }
        }
    }
    return $items;
}
```

**subdomain1** and **main** are classes, **part1** is a subdomain and **domain** is the main domain. I.e. **main** is the class for the item Products, and **subdomain1** is the class for the subitem Smartphone. Both of them are shown on domain.com, and Products is hidden on part1.domain.com. It works, but the problem is that Smartphone on subdomain part1 is ejected to the end of the menu while it was originally at the middle of the menu.

How can I do to 'keep' the position of the subitem, or the position of the hidden parent ?

Comment: When you had 'Smartphone' in the middle of the menu was that just alphabetical order (A-Z) or did you use 'order' numbers (on right of edit/quick edit view)?

Comment: @DubScrib I used the quick edit view to edit it so for sure it isn't in alphabetical order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in nav-menu.php, it wasn't too complicated.
I just changed the foreach loop content like this :

```
if($item->classes[0] == 'subdomain1' && !empty( $item->menu_item_parent )){
    $item->menu_item_parent = '';
}elseif($item->classes[0] == 'main' && $sub != 'domain'){
    unset($items[$key]);
}
```

Hope it can help !